# problem with switching between img and text in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './home-css/sectionthree.css'
import secThee from './Home-assets/sec3.jpg'


const img = ()=>{
  return <img src={secThee} draggable="false" />;
}

const secTwo = (value,active) => {
  if(active){
  switch (value) {
    case value 0:
      return <img src={secThee} draggable="false" />
      break;
    case value 1:
      return(<div className='hidden-content-one hidden-content'>
              
              <p className='hidden-title'>Text1</p>
              <p className='hidden-para'>Text1</p>
             </div>)
      break;
    case value 2:
      return(
              <div className='hidden-content-two hidden-content'>
              <p className='hidden-title'>Text2</p>
              <p className='hidden-para'>Text2</p>
              
             </div>)
      break;
    case value 3:
      return(<div className='hidden-content-three hidden-content'>
              <p className='hidden-title'>Text3</p>
              <p className='hidden-para'>Text3</p>
             </div>)
      break;
    case value 4:
      return(<div className='hidden-content-four hidden-content'>
             <p className='hidden-title'>Text4</p>
              <p className='hidden-para'>Text4</p>
             </div>)
      break;
    case value 5:
      return(<div className='hidden-content-five hidden-content'>
              
              <p className='hidden-title'>Text5</p>
              <p className='hidden-para'>Text5</p>
             </div>)
      break;
    case value 6:
      return(<div className='hidden-content-six hidden-content'>
              <p className='hidden-title'>Text6</p>
              <p className='hidden-para'>Text6</p>
             </div>)
      break;
    default:
      return <img src={secThee} draggable="false" />
      break;
  }
  }else{
    return <img src={secThee} draggable="false" />
  }
}

const hellobe = (buttonValue,buttonActive) =>{
  console.log(buttonValue,buttonActive);
}

const SectionFour = () => {
  const [hello,setHello] =useState({value:0,active:false});

  const buttonOne = () =>{
    setHello({...hello,value:1,active:!hello.active});
    return hello.value,hello.active;
  }
  const buttonTwo = () =>{
    setHello({...hello,value:2,active:!hello.active});

    return hello.value,hello.active;
  }
  
  const buttonThree = () =>{
    setHello({...hello,value:3,active:!hello.active});
    return hello.value,hello.active;
  }
  
  const buttonFour = () =>{
    setHello({...hello,value:4,active:!hello.active});
    return hello.value,hello.active;
  }
  
  const buttonFive = () =>{
    setHello({...hello,value:5,active:!hello.active});
    return hello.value,hello.active;
  }
  
  const buttonSix = () =>{
    setHello({...hello,value:6,active:!hello.active});
    return hello.value,hello.active;
  }
  return (
    <div className='section-three-container'>
        <div className='section-three grid-system'>
  
          <div className='benefits-text'>
            <p className='ben-title'>buttons</p>
            <div className='sub-benefits'>
            <div className='sub-ben text-one'>
                  
                  <button onClick={buttonOne} className='sub-ben-text'>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                    1
                  </button>
                </div>

                <div className='sub-ben text-two'>
                  <button onClick={buttonTwo} className='sub-ben-text'>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  2
                  </button>
                </div>

                <div className='sub-ben text-three'>
                  
                  <button onClick={buttonThree} className='sub-ben-text'>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  3
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div className='sub-ben text-four'>
                 
                  <button onClick={buttonFour} className='sub-ben-text'>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  4
                  </button>
                </div>

                <div className='sub-ben text-five'>
                  <button onClick={buttonFive} className='sub-ben-text'>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  5
                  </button>
                </div>
                
                <div className='sub-ben text-six'>
                  
              
                  <button onClick={buttonSix} className='sub-ben-text'>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  6
                  </button>
                  
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          {hellobe(hello.value,hello.active)}
          {secTwo(hello.value,hello.active)}
        </div>
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default SectionFour
```

I am trying to change from img to text by clicking on one of the buttons in the code below.  But when I click on the same button a second time it returns to the img.

When I click on a button, it changes it to img as expected, but when I click on any other button a second time,  even the same it returns to the img.

I tried to compare to the previous value of the state but I don't think I did it right

Comment: Can you share a sample code snippet of your code using any React Playground.

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in the code. In the switch statement, the cases should not have an assignment operation (=) inside the parentheses.

```
const secTwo = (value, active) => {
  if (active) {
    switch (value) {
      case 0:
        return <img src={secThee} draggable="false" />;
      case 1:
        return (
          <div className="hidden-content-one hidden-content">
            <p className="hidden-title">title1</p>
            <p className="hidden-para">title 1 para</p>
          </div>
        );
      case 2:
        return (
          <div className="hidden-content-two hidden-content">
            <p className="hidden-title">title 2</p>
            <p className="hidden-para">title 2 para</p>
          </div>
        );
      case 3:
        return (
          <div className="hidden-content-three hidden-content">
            <p>title 3</p>
          </div>
        );
      case 4:
        return (
          <div className="hidden-content-four hidden-content">
            <p>title 4</p>
          </div>
        );
      case 5:
        return (
          <div className="hidden-content-five hidden-content">
            <p>title 5</p>
          </div>
        );
      case 6:
        return (
          <div className="hidden-content-six hidden-content">
            <p>title 6</p>
          </div>
        );
      default:
        return <img src={secThee} draggable="false" />;
    }
  } else {
    return <img src={secThee} draggable="false" />;
  }
};
```